# Number of ways to choose 2 distinct integers from 1 to 100 such that the difference between them is at most 10

Tags: combinatorics

my try is that starting from  1 ,i can choose the next integer at max 11.So i have max 10 choices.Now coming to 2 i have choice upto 12 ,so again 10 choices and proceeding this way but i cant come to a logical conclusion

Comment: Assuming that the order in which you pick those two integers doesn't matter, I think this would be a reasonable thought. So my guess is that there are $90 \cdot 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + \cdots + 1 = 945$ ways.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: Certainly. If you choose any number between $1$ and $90$ (inclusive), and call it $x$, you can choose any number between $x+1$ and $x+10$, which gives us $10$ choices for each. If you choose $91$, for example, you have $9$ numbers to choose from (i.e. $92, 93, \cdots 100$). Similarly, $93$ gives us $8$ choices, $94$ gives us $7$, and so forth, until $99$ gives us only $1$ choice. Hence, $90 \cdot 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + \cdots + 1 = 945$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pick a number $11-90$ for the first number ($x$), there are $20$ choices for the second number($y$).
If $x<11$, there are $x+9$ choices for $y$.
If $x>90$, there are $110-x$ choices for $y$.

so: $$80*20+2*19+2*18+2*17+2*16+2*15+2*14+2*13+2*12+2*11+2*10=1890$$

This happens to count $(17,16)$ as different from $(16,17)$ so divide by $2$.
The answer is $945$ ways so @2012ssohn is correct by I hope this gives some more explanation as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force programming gave a result of 1890 pairs of $1 \leq x \neq y \leq 100, |x-y| \leq 10$, twice the result of 2012ssohn, because $(x,y) \neq (y,x)$.